# Can't install Yeoman on Windows 8 - npm ERR! peerinvalid The package yo does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies

Tags: npm, yeoman

I'm struggling to install Yeoman. Fairly new to Node and the command line in general so not really sure where to start. I searched for similar problems and tried things like
`npm cache clear` and I've tried removing some other packages like grunt which I though might be interfering, but no luck.

When I run `npm install -g yo` it seems to be OK but then it ends with this error message:

```
...
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
C:\c\Users\Matt\.node\yo -> C:\c\Users\Matt\.node\node_modules\yo\cli.js

> yo@1.1.2 postinstall C:\c\Users\Matt\.node\node_modules\yo
> node ./scripts/doctor

[Yeoman Doctor] Everything looks alright!

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package yo does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-mocha@0.1.5 wants yo@>=1.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-webapp@0.5.0 wants yo@>=1.2.0

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Matt
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Matt\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Matt@ACER_V3_571 ~
$ yo
sh.exe": yo: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the console with administrator rights?

Comment: I tried that but didn't seem to have any effect. I ended up uninstalling node and deleting all npm files and folders and then reinstalling everything. Yeoman works now so I guess there was something interfering with it.